# how to check given date time is before current date time or not with php

Tags: php

I have date-time formate like `Thu, 30 Mar 2028 04:00:00 GMT` and I want to check given date-time is before current date-time or not with PHP

for that I have use

```
function status($expire_date){
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $valid = date_create($expire_date);
    $ex_date = date_format($valid,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
     //echo $ex_date; die();

    if ($ex_date <= $current_date) {
        $status = 'Yes';
    }else{
        $status = 'No';
    }

    return $status;
}
$status = status($expire_date);
if($status == 'Yes'){
    $expire_domain_array[] = $row;
}
```

but when I make this expire_domain_array it gives me the wrong result I don't know why this is happening

can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strtotime` function to do that:

```
function isExpired($expire_date){
    return strtotime($expire_date) < strtotime('now');
}

// Check if expired
if(isExpired($expire_date)){
    echo 'expired';
} else {
    echo 'not expired';
}
```